# How to convert entrust certificate bundle to pem for haproxy ssl termination

Tags: ssl-certificate, haproxy

I don't know much about ssl certificates but I need to do ssl termination in haproxy. The team in charge of the certificate gave me a zip file which i assume is an entrust bundle when i check the crt files in it. So it seems like haproxy will only accept pem file(correct me if im wrong) and the bundle i have contains 5 files: `ca.crt <domain>.key intermediate.crt root.crt and ServerCertificate.crt` Can anyone help me on how I can convert these to a pem file that haproxy will accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to concate everything in one file.

```
cat ServerCertificate.crt intermediate.crt root.crt ca.crt <domain>.key > <domain>_haproxy.pem
```

After wards can you configure HAProxy to handle TLS/SSL as described in the doc [How to get SSL with HAProxy getting rid of stunnel, stud, nginx or pound](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/how-to-get-ssl-with-haproxy-getting-rid-of-stunnel-stud-nginx-or-pound/)